# Convert Android HexColor to int

Tags: android, hex

I can convert int to hexcolor by

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & colorInt));
```

by how do I do the opposite i.e. convert Hexcolor to int in Android.

Comment: You should use `Color.parseColor(hexColor);`. Next time you should try google search first, for simple questions.

Answer (score 0):

Take the hex part after `#` and convert to int with [`Integer.parseInt(hexstring, 16)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).